# JAVA/SELENIUM... Mostrar unicamente una seccion de mi String

Tags: java, string, selenium

estoy trabajando en Selenium y cuando hago el GetText al mensaje me sale algo como esto:

> String mensaje = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("IdMessage")).getText();

Y en la variable mensaje se captura lo siguiente:

```
Mensaje aceptado correctamente
```

entonces yo necesito tomar unicamente la palabra "correctamente", pero no lo voy a hacer con la acción **substring** que tiene java porque aveces agregan o quitan cosas de ese mensaje, pero por regla de usuario siempre debe quedar la palabra **correctamente** en el mensaje.

Estoy haciendo un condicional **if** para decir que si mi variable **mensaje** trae la palabra **correctamente** haga determinadas acciones puntualmente.

Pregunta:
Existe en Java alguna forma de obtener de una cadena String unicamente el texto puntual que se requiere?

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que deseas debes utilizar el método `contains()` de la clase `String`, el cual te permite saber si una cadena contiene otra.

```
String msg = "Mensaje aceptado correctamente";
if (msg.contains("correctamente")) {// En este caso será true
    // Código
} else {
    // Código
}
```

Answer (score 0):

También podrías almacenar ese `String` en un `array` de strings con el método `split();` y obtener la posición de la palabra **correctamente**.

```
String mensaje = "Mensaje aceptado correctamente";    
String[] aS = mensaje.split(" ");
System.out.println("Extrayendo "+aS[2]);
```

Y ya decides que hacer con el.